# How to set the Grid.column value in the style datatrigger in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a grid in row =o and column=1
On button click, i want to change this grid.row =0 and grid.column=0.
I have tried doing it by creating a style with data trigger to set the grod.column=0.As this is the local value of gris and this is not available in the style propertiea.The value of Grid.column is not getting changed.Can you please help me how can i change the grid.column value in xaml to meet my requirement.

Comment: *"I have tried doing it by ..."* - show what you have tried. I believe you are almost there, but the problem is [different](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence).

Comment: Please add the actual code you've tried so we can review it.

Comment: Also, please take a moment and read the [ask] topics. This will help you to ask well-received questions with a greater chance to get a quick answer.

Answer (score 4):

Changing column is as easy as changing value of attached property.

Below is an example with `ToggleButton` moving between first and second column depending on `IsChecked` value:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ToggleButton>
        <ToggleButton.Style>
            <Style>
                <!-- <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="0" /> optional, see below for explanation -->
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="1" />
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ToggleButton.Style>
    </ToggleButton>
</Grid>
```

Demo:

[image]

It shouldn't matter if `DataTrigger` is used.

Be aware about [value precedence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-value-precedence) when dealing with dependency properties, e.g. setting value locally will render trigger useless (you will have to use another approach, e.g. `StoryBoard` to override it):

```
<ToggleButton Grid.Column="0"> <!-- trigger will not be able to change it -->
...
```

Style setter is the right place to set initial value (see commented part in first xaml above).